# EXECUTE [SQL] AT [LINKEDSERVER] Returns Different Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, execute, linked-server

I would prefer to use openquery() unfortunately, the code is too long. I have resorted to using EXECUTE [SQL] AT [LINKEDSERVER] to get results; however, doing this returns a different result set than just running on my Oracle server directly.  I'm pasting an excerpt of the code below.  This is part of a larger UNION, but even this returns a different number of rows.  I have no idea what's going on.

```
declare @strSQL varchar(max)

set @strSQL = N'select distinct saradap_pidm as PIDM
                 ,saradap_term_code_entry as TERMCODE
                 ,replace(saradap_program_1,''+'','''') as PROGRAM
                 ,''A'' as GROUPINGDATA
  from swradap
  inner join saradap
    on swradap_pidm = saradap_pidm
    and swradap_appl_no = saradap_appl_no
    and swradap_term_code_entry = saradap_term_code_entry
    where saradap_term_code_entry in (201810,201710)
    and not exists (select ''x''
                    from saradap s2
                    cross join (select to_date(''31-JAN-18'',''dd-MON-YY'') - to_date(''30-MAR-18'',''dd-MON-YY'') as L1
                                from dual) a1
                    where s2.saradap_pidm = swradap_pidm
                    and s2.saradap_appl_no = swradap_appl_no
                    and s2.saradap_apst_code = ''W''
                    and s2.saradap_term_code_entry = swradap_term_code_entry
                    and s2.saradap_apst_date <= case when swradap_term_code_entry = 201810
                                                           then ''30-MAR-18''
                                                           else trim(to_date(''25-JAN-17'',''dd-MON-YY'')-L1) end)
    and swradap_activity_date = (select max(s2.swradap_activity_date)
                                from swradap s2
                                cross join (select to_date(''31-JAN-18'',''dd-MON-YY'') - to_date(''30-MAR-18'',''dd-MON-YY'') as L1
                                            from dual) a1
                                where s2.swradap_pidm = saradap_pidm
                                and s2.swradap_appl_no = saradap_appl_no
                                and s2.swradap_term_code_entry = saradap_term_code_entry
                                and s2.swradap_activity_date <= case when saradap_term_code_entry = 201810
                                                                     then ''30-MAR-18''
                                                                     else trim(to_date(''25-JAN-17'',''dd-MON-YY'')-L1) end)'

execute (@strSQL) AT [PROD]
```

Comment: Check your definition of the linked server and confirm it is indeed connected to what you think.

Comment: It is definitely the same server and it is using the same credentials I use to run the query directly.  It may have something to do with the date stuff, but I can't be sure...

Comment: Are the results wildly different or a little different? You might be reading uncommitted data in one connection and committed in another.

Comment: Wildly.  I think I need to write the dates differently, but I'm not sure of another way to do them.

EDIT:  I may have figured it out.  Looks like if I replace ''30-MAR-18'' with trim(to_date(''30-MAR-18'',''dd-MON-YY'')) then it works!

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured it out. Looks like if I replace ''30-MAR-18'' with trim(to_date(''30-MAR-18'',''dd-MON-YY'')) then it works.  I have new issues now, but at least that is solved.